# Renaming Content Type on Variants Page

Tags: nodes

[image]

I am trying to figure how to rename this field. I know for example with this content type, I can go into the content type and edit the field name for this content type, but that will give the new name to my other variants using this content type (if I'm not wrong).

Is there anyway to change the name of this one specific piece of content without editing anything else?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to change '"Node being viewed" Body' to something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little new to Drupal, but yes, if I could change that text or even "nody:body" to make it more descriptive. Is there a way to do that?